# RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout when setting onClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

RecyclerView seems to stop working when I try to implement an onClickListener in the ViewHolder. I can't figure out why.

I've tried using runOnUiThread to set up the adapter. I've also tried setting the adapter to null in onCreate, but neither of those solutions seem to be working.

I've looked on the other stack overflow posts with similar issues, but cannot find the right solution to get this to work.

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.eijaz.popularmovies

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import java.io.IOException
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import okhttp3.*
import java.util.logging.Logger.global


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val URL_MAIN = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3"
    val POPULAR_MOVIES = "/movie/popular"
    val TOP_RATED_MOVIES = "movie/top_rated"

    val URL_INDIVIDUAL_MOVIE = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/"
    val POSTER_SIZE = "w185"

    val ENTER_API_KEY = "?api_key="
    val API_KEY = "67bfdc871eabed5845200d39e64ed6e5"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        fetchJson()

        rv_poster_list.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2)
    }

    fun fetchJson() {
        println("Attempting to Fetch JSON")

        val request = Request.Builder().url(URL_MAIN + POPULAR_MOVIES + ENTER_API_KEY + API_KEY).build()

        val client = OkHttpClient()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
                val body = response?.body()?.string()
                println(body)

                val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

                val homeFeed = gson.fromJson(body, HomeFeed::class.java)

                runOnUiThread {
                    rv_poster_list.adapter = MovieAdapter(homeFeed)
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
                println("Failed to execute request")
            }
        })
    }
}


ackage com.example.eijaz.popularmovies

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import java.io.IOException
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import okhttp3.*
import java.util.logging.Logger.global


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val URL_MAIN = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3"
    val POPULAR_MOVIES = "/movie/popular"
    val TOP_RATED_MOVIES = "movie/top_rated"

    val URL_INDIVIDUAL_MOVIE = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/"
    val POSTER_SIZE = "w185"

    val ENTER_API_KEY = "?api_key="
    val API_KEY = "67bfdc871eabed5845200d39e64ed6e5"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        fetchJson()

        rv_poster_list.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2)
    }

    fun fetchJson() {
        println("Attempting to Fetch JSON")

        val request = Request.Builder().url(URL_MAIN + POPULAR_MOVIES + ENTER_API_KEY + API_KEY).build()

        val client = OkHttpClient()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
                val body = response?.body()?.string()
                println(body)

                val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

                val homeFeed = gson.fromJson(body, HomeFeed::class.java)

                runOnUiThread {
                    rv_poster_list.adapter = MovieAdapter(homeFeed)
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
                println("Failed to execute request")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

MovieAdapter.kt

```
package com.example.eijaz.popularmovies

import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.poster_list_item.view.*


class MovieAdapter(val homeFeed: HomeFeed) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>() {

    val URL_MAIN = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3"
    val POPULAR_MOVIES = "/movie/popular"
    val TOP_RATED_MOVIES = "movie/top_rated"

    val URL_INDIVIDUAL_MOVIE = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/"
    val POSTER_SIZE = "w185"

    val ENTER_API_KEY = "?api_key="
    val API_KEY = "67bfdc871eabed5845200d39e64ed6e5"

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return homeFeed.results.count()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
        val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.poster_list_item, parent, false)
        return CustomViewHolder(cellForRow)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder?, position: Int) {

        val posterPath = homeFeed.results.get(position).poster_path
        val posterUrl = URL_INDIVIDUAL_MOVIE + POSTER_SIZE + posterPath

        val ivMoviePoster = holder?.view?.iv_movie_poster
        Picasso.with(holder?.view?.context).load(posterUrl).into(ivMoviePoster)

    }

}

class CustomViewHolder(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    init {
        view.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(view.context, DetailActivity::class.java)

            view.context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not because of the `onClickListener`. It's because you are not attaching the adapter initially. What you need to do is attach an empty adapter `MovieAdapter` in the `onCreate` method and then after you fetch the data you can set the data in the adapter and call `notifydatasetchanged`. So something like `rv_poster_list.adapter = MovieAdapter(Homefeed())` and then once your data is loaded inside `fetchJson()` you can call `rv_poster_list.adapter.homefeed = <data>`